# PadLeft with spaces

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Have a relatively simple request.

I wish to pad left a string with spaces in an HTML page using VB on asp.net

For me the most obvious way to do it is

```
Response.Write(qty.PadLeft(5, " ") + " x " + part_number)
```

but as HTML does not render multiple spaces, this does not work

my workaround is

```
Response.Write(qty.PadLeft(5, "0") + " x " + part_number)
```

which pads the number with zero's but looks fairly unappealing on the website.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Update:
Based on replies so far I have tried

```
"100".PadLeft(5, "&nbsp;")
```

but this outputs `&&100`

Comment: My 0.02: &nbsp;

Comment: FWIW, there's a reason that HTML collapses multiple spaces.  You might be better off working with HTML rather than fighting it - why not instead put your text into some structured elements and use CSS etc to get the alignments correct.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it by doing this

```
rep = string.concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", 5-qty.Length))
Response.Write(rep + qty+ " x " + part_number)
```

Not the best but works.

Answer (score 0):

There's & nbsp; or setting  or the css (with white-space) to see spaces. If you want to align information, you might want to also look at having a [fixed font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).